# Can I batch together an add() and a set() operation in cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

From [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes), we get that:

> **Batched writes**
>
> If you do not need to read any documents in your operation set, you can execute multiple write operations as a single batch that contains **any combination of set(), update(), or delete() operations.** A batch of writes completes atomically and can write to multiple documents.

But in my case, I need to be sure that an `add()` operation (creating a new document) will happen together with a `set()` operation to update some other pre-existing document.

Is there a way to do this?

**Note:** I'm using the Javascrip SDK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do

```
 const batch = firestore().batch()
 const sampleRef = firestore().collection(‘sample’)
 const id = sampleRef.doc().id
 batch.set(sampleRef.doc(id), {...})
 batch.commit()
```

It should do thé trick, its thé same as add

Comment: Thanks! That could work. But so far I'm using Firestore auto-generated ids. Don't know exactly why, but I'm trying to stick to that.

Comment: @cbdev420 fear no more brother, I've updated my answer to give you a firestore autogenerated id, basically, you can pre-generated it before committing the batch op

Comment: That's awesome! Will definetely try that! Thanks

Comment: keep crushing it

Comment: It works! Solved my problem. Because I was really needing that generated ID in advance to use as a "foreign key" inside this other document. Thanks!

Comment: glad it helps brother!

Answer (score 2):

Just use the CollectionReference's [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) method followed by a call to the BatchedWrite's [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch#set) method, in order to "mimic" a call to the `add()` method,

Excerpt from https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc:

> If no path is specified, **an automatically-generated unique ID**
>   will be used for the returned `DocumentReference`.

Therefore, in your batch you can do:

```
// Get a new write batch
var batch = db.batch();

// A "standard" Set
var nycRef = db.collection("cities").doc("NYC");
batch.set(nycRef, {name: "New York City"});

// A Set that is similar to an Add
var unknownCityRef = db.collection("cities").doc();
batch.set(unknownCityRef, {name: "Unknown City"});

// Commit the batch
batch.commit().then(function () {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that!

Comment: @cbdev420 Note that there was a typo in the code! `unknownCityRef` was not correctly passed to `batch.set()`! Corrected!

Answer (score 1):

In order to create new document equivalent to add() using batch writes we need
to first generate the uid through use of createID() function from angularfirestore and set batch.

However, updating the existing document is pretty straight forward. We simply provide its uid while setting the batch.

`

```
constructor(
    private angularFireStore: AngularFirestore,
   ) {}

 const batch = this.angularFireStore.firestore.batch();

 // generates the unique uid of 20 chars 
 const autogenUid = this.angularFireStore.createId();
 // this is new doc ref with newly generated uid
 const collectionReference = this.angularFireStore.collection
                            ('collection_name').doc(autogenUid).ref;

 const docData = {first_field:'value', second_field:'value2'};
 batch.set(collectionReference, docData);

 // to update existing , we simply need to know its uid beforehand, 
 const collection2Reference = this.angularFireStore.collection
                            ('collection2_name').doc('existingUid').ref;

 const docData2 = {first_field:'value', second_field:'value2'};
 batch.set(collection2Reference, docData2);

 batch.commit();
```